# Tiny yolo v4 usage with opencv gives no detection

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, yolo, transfer-learning

I have trained yolo-tiny-v4 on custom dataset on google colab and the detection works well . Then I've tried to load the yolo-tiny-v4 in other colab [project](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1pGEOFP9hq7Hdv4rgwtxzfJyis-1SBeoB#scrollTo=7aJFz_KzBaYK) with help of opencv's dnn module, no error appears, but the detection fails (no object detected, the output of the detection is a vector of Nan).

```
[array([[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,  0.],
    [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,  0.],
    [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,  0.],
    ...,
    [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,  0.],
    [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,  0.],
    [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,  0.]], dtype=float32),
array([[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,  0.],
    [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,  0.],
    [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,  0.],
    ...,
    [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,  0.],
    [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,  0.],
    [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,  0.]], dtype=float32)]
```

I'm using OpenCV Version 4.5.1 and Python 3.7 on colab. Any idea ?

This is the code

```
#Load YOLO
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet("/content/custom-yolov4-tiny-detector.cfg","/content/custom-yolov4- 
tiny-detector_last.weights")
classes = []  
with open("obj.names","r") as f:
classes = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
net.getLayerNames()
layer_names = net.getLayerNames()
outputlayers = [layer_names[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
#loading image
img = cv2.imread("/content/1.png")
#img = cv2.resize(img,None,fx=0.4,fy=0.3)
height,width,channels = img.shape
cv2_imshow(img)
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img,0.00392,(416,416),(0,0,0),True,crop=False)
net.setInput(blob)
outs = net.forward(outputlayers)
outs
```

Comment: does the same code work with a pretrained tiny yolo v3 model? Did you try with a pretrained tiny yolo v4?

Comment: i will try this and come back with feedback

Comment: @Micka Hi i made funny mistake  as a beginner  forgetting to install darknet in cola. Now everything works great thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a beginner i forgot to install darknet in colab

Comment: Hi do you mind elaborate what install mean? I already make the darknet in colab but still it give me nan in prediction. Thanks

Comment: I have this same problem when running Python3 test app using opencv on ubuntu and odroid xu4. Same tiny model pre-trained on custom data set works well on windows machine but not on ubuntu. Also, My understanding is that darknet is not needed for detection but for training models.